# Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms won't render a report as CSV

Tags: c#, csv, reporting-services

I have a LocalReport with 400 or so columns that I'm trying to render to Excel, but the version of Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms that I'm using supports only 256 columns. Therefore I'm trying to get it to render as CSV instead in case the Excel export fails:

```
try
{
    // render the report
    bytes = Report.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
}
catch (LocalProcessingException ex)
{
    // fall back on CSV rendering
    bytes = Report.Render(
            "CSV",
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
}
```

However I get an error when I do this:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: format

So it seems that CSV is an invalid report format - but I thought CSV was supported? How can I get my LocalReport to render as CSV?

Thanks! :)

edit: here is where I set the XML for deviceInfo:

```
switch (type)
{
    // TODO: implement other cases
    case ReportContentType.HTML:
        reportType = "HTML";
        break;
    case ReportContentType.Excel:
        reportType = "Excel";
        break;
    case ReportContentType.Word:
        reportType = "Word";
        break;
    case ReportContentType.PDF:
    default:
        reportType = "PDF";
        break;
}

//string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo/>";
string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
$"<OutputFormat>{reportType}</OutputFormat>" +
$"<PageWidth>{width}in</PageWidth>" +
$"<PageHeight>{height}in</PageHeight>" +
$"<MarginTop>{marginTop}in</MarginTop>" +
$"<MarginLeft>{marginLeft}in</MarginLeft>" +
$"<MarginRight>{marginRight}in</MarginRight>" +
$"<MarginBottom>{marginBottom}in</MarginBottom>" +
"</DeviceInfo>";
```

So the reportType would be Excel since that's what the user requested; should I change it to CSV? The others are just numbers of course.

Comment: Have you considered not using SSRS for this? Why not use a library that's specifically made for CSV files, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)?

Comment: Well, there are lots of other reports that need to be rendered to HTML/PDF/Word/Excel - still, I suppose I could call that library from the catch block, if I knew exactly where all the data was coming from - I've got a custom XML report format which is translated into something SSRS can understand somewhere or other in the code, and digging into that might take a while!

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: `deviceInfo` contains a block of XML. Could you please show that value?

Comment: Which version? I think it's 10.0.0.0, according to the Object Browser in Visual Studio.